# Gyroscope - Transform data to correct coordinate system

Tags: rotational-dynamics, acceleration, coordinate-systems, angular-velocity, gyroscopes

I have some data on linear acceleration ($m/s^2$) and angular velocity ($rad/s$) recorded from an electronic sensor over time.

I realized that the sensor had been displaced in its position during recording and I therefore need to perform a data correction mapping. So, assuming that the current coordinate system needs slight rotations in $XZ$ and $YZ$ planes to be corrected, correcting the linear acceleration data will be easy using a [rotation matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix).

What about angular velocity of the gyroscope? AFAIK using usual vector calculus (i.e rotation matrix), transformation of angular velocity is not possible (*true?*). I've got the angular velocity of the gyroscope along 3 axes ($\omega_x$, $\omega_y$, $\omega_z$), and I need some transformation map to calculate correct angular velocities ($\omega'_x$, $\omega'_y$, $\omega'_z$).

[image: Coordinate system A and B]

---

**TL;DR** Is there an approach similar to using rotation matrix in case of angular velocity / spin, to transform data from rotated coordinate system $A$ to correct coordinate system $B$, when rotations applied in both $XZ$ and $YZ$ planes?

Comment: is it correct to say you have a set of vectors in 1 coord. frame and are trying to find what they would be in another?

Comment: @lineage thanks for corrections, and yes, I have linear acceleration vectors and angular velocity data in rotated coordinate system A and trying to find what they would be in unrotated coordinate system B. BTW I don't know how to achieve this in case of angular velocity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of what the nature of the recorded data is, all vectors transform the same. In other words, it doesn't matter whether its $\vec{a}$ or $\vec{\omega}$ as long as its a vector quantity. Whatever you used to correct the linear accelerations, $\vec{a}$, can exactly be used for $\vec{\omega}$ as long as the orientation of the sensor was fixed during recording.

Be careful though as to what needs to be rotated: the sensor or the vectors.
If $B=R A$, then $\vec{a}'=R^{-1}\vec{a}$.

Comment: Thanks. so, you say that $\omega$ acts as a plain vector? I ask this, because the nature of angular velocity is not clear to me. assuming that angular velocity is a plain vector... sounds weird to me. :D In my opinion, angular velocity seems to be semi-scalar / semi-vector!

Comment: its a vector since its a cross product.(yeah its a pseudo-vector but thats important during inversions)

Comment: Also, note that for rotation vectors $R^{-1} = R^\top$